# Hosting existing web services in sharepoint 2010

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2010

I have a set of web services coded. Need to create an application combining some of share point 2010 features plus functionalities of my services. I was thinking of deploying the services as a part of the sharepoint application (in a virtual directory) i'm building [Not hosting as a separate application elsewhere since I do not want the service calls(script calls) to end up cross-domain]

Is this the right approach. If yes, what needs to be ensured while making my services a part of a sharepoint application using a virtual directory

Comment: @Marek: I have a set of services already coded in .net (which is no way related to sharepoint). Now I want to create a sharepoint application which consumes these services. I want them to be a part of the same application implies the services should be accessible via the same url (other than _vti_bin would be good for a better logical separation)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SPDev](http://blog.crsw.com/spdev/) tool to generate the SharePoint web service *disco.aspx* and *wsdl.aspx* files:

```
SPDev.exe -o GenWS -url http://Central-Administration-URL -asmx CustomWS.asmx
```

Then deploy all needed assemblies to GAC and copy the *.asmx*, *disco.aspx*, *wsdl.aspx* files to the `14 hive\ISAPI` folder.

---

I don't think you can have path other than `_vti_bin` (or `_vti_adm` if deployed the service to the `14 hive\ADMISAPI` folder), but you can deploy the web services to a subfolder and use URL like `http://Site/_vti_bin/CustomDotNetWebServices/CustomWS.asmx`.

---

SharePoint 2010 supports custom services - both ASP.NET and WCF ones:

- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom ASP.NET Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx)
- [Creating a Custom WCF Service in SharePoint Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521581.aspx)